# Can someone please explain why `this` is different in these two cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

```
let obj = {
    one: function(){
        this.two();
    },

    two: function(){
        console.log("two");
    }
}

let oneFunc = obj.one;

obj.one(); // two

oneFunc(); // TypeError: this.two is not a function
```

I have been programming in JavaScript for quite some time. I thought I had a really solid grasp on the `this` keyword. However, I ran in to this today and it blew my mind. I can't figure out why this is happening. When I call `oneFunc()`, `this` refers to the global object. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because `this` depends on who calls the function and how it is called.

Comment: `this` refers to the object witch calls the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refere to the object, and what you are doing here is creating a function equal to the methode of the object and so you lose the reference to the object.

You can use bind

```
let obj = {
    one: function(){
        this.two();
    },

    two: function(){
        console.log("two");
    }
}

let oneFunc = obj.one;
oneFunc = oneFunc.bind(obj);

obj.one(); // two

oneFunc(); // TypeError: this.two is not a function
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Still seems pretty weir though. I am amazed that I haven't run into this problem before. Thanks.